# How do I change the font of a specific item in a CListBox/CComboBox

Tags: c++, mfc, ccombobox, clistbox

I have a CComboBox-derived class with a subclassed CListBox.  I would like to make the first two item in the CListBox bold.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an owner-draw listbox, and override DrawItem() to draw the items. For the first two, you can use a different font than the rest.